# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.categoryMap.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem calling functions of the Map (get, set, keys, etc) in my function. The map is returned from a firebase query.

Below is my sample code:

```
categoryMap = new Map<Number, String>();

//called onInit.
loadList() {
this.firestore.firestore.collection('skillType').doc('content')
  .get().then(res => {
      this.categoryMap = res.data().list;
      });
}

sampleFunction() {
    //myMap is a dummy map that I took from internet.
    var myMap = new Map();
    myMap.set(0, 'dummy'); //the function can be called.
    console.log(myMap.get(0)); //Can get output.
    console.log(this.categoryMap.get(1)); //Get the error message as title
}
```

This is the `categoryMap` after calling `loadList()`:

```
1: "Development & IT"
2: "Design & Creative"
3: "Accounting & Consulting"
4: "Translation & Language"
5: "Sales & Marketing"
6: "Sports & Fitness"
7: "Academic & Curricular"
8: "Culinary"
9: "Labor work"
```

The values are there, but why cant I call any of the function to get my data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a promise issue, the issue is that loadList resolves immediately and you do not wait for it to finish. This is where you need to use async/await over promise chaining. Below is an example of how this issue could be solved, you can integrate it into your above solution depending on your requirements.

```
let categoryMap = new Map<Number, String>();

const populateList = async() => {
  const snapshot = await firestore.firestore.collection('skillType').doc('content').get()
  categoryMap = snapshot.data().list
}

const sampleFunction = async() => {
  // Only populate it when you need it if possible
  // If not do in the onInit method
  await populateList()
  // Now the map is populated
  console.log(categoryMap.get(1)) 
}
sampleFunction()
```